# Django url passing more than one parameter

Tags: python, django, django-urls

in my django project i create in urls.py file an entry like this one:

```
....
url(r'^pd/<str:df>/<str:dt>/<int:v_id>/<str:interval>', calc_q),
...
```

because i need to pass different params to my calc_q function.
Well when i start my django project and try to call my url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/pd/2021-06-27/2021-06-29/17/15min/
```

i get an error:

> ...

> 4. ^pd/str:df/str:dt/int:v_id/str:interval

> ...

> The current path, pd/2021-06-27/2021-06-29/17/15min/, didn't match any of these.

Why djngo cannot find my url in url list?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you are mixing the regex syntax that **`url(…)`** and [**`re_path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path) use with the syntax for a [**`path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.path). You thus work with a `path` like:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [ScopedTypeVariables
    # …,
    path('pd/<str:df>/<str:dt>/<int:v_id>/<str:interval>/', calc_q),
    # …
]
```

Comment: Thanks so mutcch but I get The current path, pd/2021-06-27/2021-06-29/17/15min/, didn't match any of these. again

Comment: @ManuelSanti: what are the paths that have been tried?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/pd/2021-06-27/2021-06-29/17/15min/

Comment: @ManuelSanti: there was also a trailing slash missing, so `<str:interval>/` instead of `<str:interval>`.